# Why won't this link render?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an if/else statement in my details view like so:

```
 @if (Model.SomeProperty != null)
    {
        Html.RenderAction("MethodName", "ContollerName", new {id=stuff});
    }
    else
    { 
        <span>Is this showing?</span>
        Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "MethodName", "ContollerName", new { Id = something}, null);
    }
```

The span renders, so I know the else block was hit, but the ActionLink doesn't appear. However, if I move it out of the else block like this, it works:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "MethodName", "ContollerName", new { Id = something}, null)
```

I'm guessing it's something wrong with my syntax, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink()` returns a string (actual an `IHtmlString`) containing an `<a>` tag.

You aren't doing anything with that string.

You need to print the string to the page by writing `@Html.ActionLink(...)`.  (you can still do that in a code block)

Comment: Ok. I got an error when I had an @ symbol on the html.RenderAction helper inside the if block, so I (incorrectly) assumed I would need to remove it from the html.ActionLink helper as well in the else block. I need to buy a book! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the `@`! Just add it.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
@if (Model.SomeProperty != null)
{
    Html.RenderAction("MethodName", "ContollerName", new {id=stuff});
}
else
{
    <span>Is this showing?</span>
    @Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "MethodName", "ContollerName", new { Id = something}, null);
}
```

The `Html.RenderAction` works directly with stream so it doesn't need it, but `Html.ActionLink` returns `MvcHtmlString` which needs to be outputed "in place".